# Listview displaying only last item in each row?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-volley

I am retrieving JSON Array of object from php Server and displaying it on the ListView, I am successfully able to retrive data and store it into the Arraylist but when I am trying to display it on the ListView, Only the last Item is showing multiple times.
I am Using Volley callback interface to store data,
and using ListFragment. Here is my code:

```
Server.getDataFromServer(getActivity(), "product.php", new Server.VolleyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccessResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                mProduct.setId(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("mId"));
                mProduct.setName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mName"));
                mProduct.setPrice(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("mPrice"));
                mProducts.add(mProduct);

                System.out.println(mProducts.get(i));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.home_list_row, mProducts);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
);
```

**And here is onCreateView**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    return rootView;
}
```

[android monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJNIK.png)

[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlzfm.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have created only one instance of Product `mProduct`

by each setter the previuos values are overriden

in `mProducts` you have added same instance 3 times

```
for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
    mProduct.setId(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("mId"));
    mProduct.setName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mName"));
    mProduct.setPrice(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("mPrice"));
    mProducts.add(mProduct);

    System.out.println(mProducts.get(i)); // shows you what you want, because you are in the loop
}

for(Product product: mProducts){
    System.out.println(product); // shows, what is realy in the ArrayList. it is always last value
}
```

what you need is

```
for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setId(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("mId"));
    product.setName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mName"));
    product.setPrice(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("mPrice"));
    mProducts.add(product);

    System.out.println(mProducts.get(i));
}

for(Product product: mProducts){
    System.out.println(product); // now you have all values
}
```

Comment: Works like charm